# NOT LIKE MySQL statement

Tags: mysql, select, sql-like

I have an issue with NOT LIKE statement. I have two sql tables setup as tag map. First table finds tag_id according to the search name and second finds resource_id based on tag_id found. When I run a NOT LIKE statement below, I receive the result: resource_id = 1.

#### Tag map tables

```
tag_id name
1      meat
2      vegetarian

resource_id tag_id
1           1
1           2
```

#### Query

```
SELECT 
    f.id, f.food_name, tm.resource_id, tm.tag_id, t.name 
FROM 
    tag as t, tagmap as tm JOIN item as f ON 
    (
        f.id = tm.resource_id AND tm.tag_id IN 
        (
        SELECT 
            t.tag_id 
        FROM 
            tag as t 
        WHERE 
            t.name NOT LIKE '%meat%' 
        ) 
     )
GROUP by f.id
```

All I need this query to do is, if it finds a resource_id with tag name "meat" I don't want it to return this resource_id.

If my explanation is not clear please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you must search for:

```
select resource_id
from tagmap
where resource_id not in (select resource_id
                          from tagmap
                          where tag_id in (select tag_id from tag
                                           where name like '%meat%'));
```

or with a `join`:

```
select *
from tagmap
where resource_id not in (select m.resource_id
                          from tagmap m, tag t
                          where m.tag_id = t.tag_id and t.name like '%meat%');
```

You look for `resource_id` with name "meat" and exclude these `not in` in your select.

This *might* correspond to your query, but I'm not really sure:

```
select f.id, f.food_name, tm.resource_id, tm.tag_id, t.name 
from tag as t, tagmap as tm, item as f
where f.id = tm.resource_id
      and tm.tag_id = t.tag_id
      and tm.resource_id not in (select m.resource_id
                                 from tagmap m, tag t
                                 where m.tag_id = t.tag_id
                                       and t.name like '%meat%')
group by f.id;
```

Comment: Same result as for the above query. It displays resource_id = 1.

Comment: @YuryLankovskiy You're right, please look at the modified answer.

Comment: I don't clearly understand your answer ... as to how to modify my code with minimal adjustments.

I'm going to try to replace your statement with mine and see if it works with the rest of the code.

Comment: It seems to do what I require, however, how would I modify it to receive field values attached to resource_id. In specific, f.id and f.food_name as presented in my original code.

Thanks

Comment: @YuryLankovskiy Look at the amended answer. I don't fully understand your requirements, so this might or might not work.

Comment: This works as intended, let me test on my server ... I need to open up a book on sql to start learning this stuff

Answer (score 1):

I am not %100 sure I understand what you expect on your query result, but from what I understand this might help you:

```
SELECT f.id, f.food_name, tm.resource_id, tm.tag_id, t.name 
FROM tag as t
left join tagmap as tm on tm.resource_id = t.tag_id
left join item as f on f.id = tm.resource_id
where t.name NOT LIKE '%meat%' 
GROUP by f.id
```

And to play with query, here sqlfiddle sample:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/561c4/7

Edit:

So you want to exclude any resource attached to selected tag, try this:

```
SELECT f.id, f.food_name, tm.resource_id, tm.tag_id, t.name 
FROM tag AS t 
INNER JOIN tagmap AS tm ON tm.resource_id = t.tag_id 
INNER JOIN item AS f ON f.id = tm.resource_id 
where tm.resource_id not in (
  select resource_id from tagmap 
  where tag_id in (select tag_id from tag WHERE name LIKE '%meat%')
)  
GROUP by f.id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/053fa/3

Comment: I'm running the query here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ead20/1 and I'm receiving the correct result ... however when I run the query on the server I'm receiving resource_id = 2 and 3...

Comment: try to make left join to inner join.

Comment: Actually ... I'm running a query here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31120/1 and it's returning the same result as on my server. Any idea?

Comment: INNER or LEFT JOIN has the same result.

Comment: what is your expected output because I can't see an error? query returns all other tags except meat?

Comment: It returns tags including ones that have meat ... if you observe the piece of code from sql

    INSERT INTO `tagmap` VALUES (1, 1, 1);
    INSERT INTO `tagmap` VALUES (2, 1, 2);
    INSERT INTO `tagmap` VALUES (3, 2, 1);
    INSERT INTO `tagmap` VALUES (4, 2, 2);
    INSERT INTO `tagmap` VALUES (5, 5, 1);
    INSERT INTO `tagmap` VALUES (6, 3, 2);
    INSERT INTO `tagmap` VALUES (7, 4, 3);

You can see that resource_id 2 should not be returned as it has a tag "meat" attached to it, however, it does return it.

Sorry, don't know how to edit comment text so the values are not inline.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work here, I'm suppose to get 2 results but instead only 1 is returned http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2f69/1

Comment: I still don't get it, accepted answers query is exactly same as mine and returns 1 row (and has to be 1 row not 2) but glad you solved your problem.

Comment: It should return two rows, 3 and 4.